# How To Create An Auto Random Number Field In MySQL?

Tags: mysql, random, primary-key

I'm working on a database for my website that needs to generate unique random 8 digit numbers as the primary key. I know its possible via PHP but if the generated number is currently in the database I need to do some additional calls. So I wanna prevent these calls to the database and reduce the website traffic. So I'm looking for something like what MS Access uses for the auto number data type. take a look at the properties table in these pictures:

[image]

And here is the results:

[image]

Comment: Create a trigger and use the rand function to insert a random number or use the uuid function to generate really unique ids

Comment: It looks like a working solution. let me test it.